# Create rogue AP inside network

Tags: linux, wireless-access-point, kali-linux

so far I've manged to create an evil-twin with Linux using two wireless-cards and bridge them, giving internet access to clients. Problem is that clients have to manually connect to my fake AP.
my question is, if i have access to the original wireless network, can i configure the fake AP as a range-extender or something, making clients automatically connect to it, if it has stronger signal? or am i missing something here?

Comment: That very much depends on the AP; first, you'd need access to change the configuration; second, it would need to be capable of doing that.

Comment: thanks a lot. i thought wifi-repeaters work differently, but did some readings and it was not what i thought.